# Sum two columns from two differents tables and add the result into a third table

Tags: mysql, triggers, sum

I have a question regarding a database, where there are two tables (one being for the seller and the other for flexuser) in these two tables we have a column of the number of ads that each one has, these two are linked by a business code (foreign key) that relate them to a third table (enterprise). This table also has a column for the number of ads, and the value would be the sum of ads from all sellers and flexusers that have your company code. I need to perform this operation automatically through a trigger, but I've been getting an error.
Code:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_empresarial (
    id_empresarial INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_empresarial),
    nome_empresarial VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email_empresarial VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    senha_empresarial VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    membros_empresarial INT,
    cnpj_empresarial VARCHAR(25),
    enter_empresarial DATETIME,
    qtdanuncios_empresarial INT
)  DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE tb_vendedor (
    id_vendedor INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_vendedor),
    nome_vendedor VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email_vendedor VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    senha_vendedor VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    tel_vendedor VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    doc_vendedor VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    cep_vendedor VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    nasc_vendedor DATE NOT NULL,
    enter_vendedor DATETIME,
    qtdanuncios_vendedor INT,
    code_empresarial INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (code_empresarial)
        REFERENCES tb_empresarial (id_empresarial)
)  DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE tb_flexuser (
    id_flexuser INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_flexuser),
    nome_flexuser VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email_flexuser VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    senha_flexuser VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    tel_flexuser VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    doc_flexuser VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    cep_flexuser VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    nasc_flexuser DATE NOT NULL,
    enter_flexuser DATETIME,
    qtdanuncios_flexuser INT,
    code_empresarial INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (code_empresarial)
        REFERENCES tb_empresarial (id_empresarial)
)  DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

create trigger anunciosempresa after insert on tb_empresarial for each row set e.qtdanuncios_empresarial =  ( SELECT 
    SUM(v.qtdanuncios_vendedor + f.qtdanuncios_flexuser) AS qtdanuncios_vendedor
FROM
    tb_vendedor AS v
        INNER JOIN
    tb_flexuser AS f ON 
    v.code_empresarial = f.code_empresarial);
```

The error is normally linked to a bad positioning or inability to find a variable.

I would like to add the value of two columns from two different tables and place the sum value into a third column of a third table automatically with the trigger.

Comment: You need to reference 'NEW' keyword which represents newly inserted or updated row in a trigger

Comment: Did you really want SUM of + ?

Comment: It is usually better to compute stuff as you SELECT, not in a TRIGGER.  Please explain why you want a trigger.